# Assistance with expanding a Sublime Text Plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have a sublime text plugin that watches for the creation of files beginning with lp_

When a file with lp_ prefix is created the plugin creates a folder of the same name with an images folder within.

I would like to watch different areas of my site and create the relevant folder within the nearest lp folder to the created file.

For example I have the following folder strucure

Root > desktop >
Root > desktop > lp

Root > Mobile >
Root > Mobile > lp

Root > Tablet >
Root > Tablet > lp

When a file with lp_ prefix is created in either 'device' folder I would like folder to be created within the nearest lp folder.

The plugin below is along the right lines but I am unsure as how to set rules for targeting specific folders.

import sublime, sublime_plugin, os

```
# We extend event listener
class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    # This method is called every time a file is saved (not only the first time is saved)
    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        variables = view.window().extract_variables()
        fileBaseName = variables['file_base_name'] # File name without extension
        path = '/Users/jameshusband/Dropbox/development/remote/superfreeslotgames.com/css/' + fileBaseName
        imagepath = path + '/images/'

        if fileBaseName.startswith('lp_') and not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
            os.mkdir(imagepath)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this? I am not very experienced with Python so am unsure of the best way to achieve my goal.

Comment: As you can see in [sublime API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) extracted variables contains also `file_path` (`variables['file_path']`). If I have understood your problem right you only need to test the path of the file being saved to decide what folder to use.

Comment: Glad your back Sergio, I have been trying to figure this out using available docs but getting a bit lost. How can i check against the location of the saved file to determine where to create folder?

Comment: If the file you are saving is inside _/root/desktop_ then save it to _/root/desktop/whatever/lp_. Maybe you can use startswith to see if the file path starts with _/root/desktop_

Comment: so just using standard if else statements?

Comment: Why not? I'm not sure if it will work, try testing it.

Comment: Ok iv done some testing, console returns error:

NameError: global name 'file_path' is not defined


Using following code update:

        if fileBaseName.startswith('lp_') and not os.path.exists(path) and file_path.startswith('/css/'):
            os.mkdir(path)
            os.mkdir(imagepath)

Comment: It looks like you haven't even defined file_path variable. `file_path = variables['file_path']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85095/discussion-between-james-and-sergiofc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to SergioFC for helping out with this!

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os


# We extend event listener
class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    # This method is called every time a file is saved (not only the first time is saved)
    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        variables = view.window().extract_variables()
        fileBaseName = variables['file_base_name'] # File name without extension
        file_path = variables['file_path']

        if fileBaseName.startswith('lp_'):

            if file_path.endswith('/desktop'):
                path = file_path + '/lp/' + fileBaseName
                imagepath = path + '/images/'
                os.mkdir(path)
                os.mkdir(imagepath)
                open(path + '/' + "style.css", 'w')

            if file_path.endswith('/tablet'):
                path = file_path + '/lp/' + fileBaseName
                imagepath = path + '/images/'
                os.mkdir(path)
                os.mkdir(imagepath)
                open(path + '/' + "style.css", 'w')

            if file_path.endswith('/mobile'):
                path = file_path + '/lp/' + fileBaseName
                imagepath = path + '/images/'
                os.mkdir(path)
                os.mkdir(imagepath)
                open(path + '/' + "style.css", 'w')
```

Expanding from here would be to upload lp folder content on save of lp_ file, then set user options for multi purpose